# IE8 won't upload files with names longer than 130 characters. Why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, file-upload

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/pyLyu/) with a file input and some Javascript to paste the DOM-ostensible value back onto the page.

It appears that for files whose names total length (including the dot and extension) exceeds 130 characters [1], the change event fires but the input does not accept the new file.

Why is this? Is there a way around it?

[1] For example (validator demands I put code in):
`123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456.789`

Comment: I'm inclined to say that "there is no way around it" (I believe I've seen this issue before and that was the resolution, but then again, that might have been in the 0's), and a conjecture that the reason is "Why on earth would anyone have a file 130 characters long?" But neither of those opinions are official enough to create an answer.

Comment: I think that might be as close to an answer as I can get. Doesn't seem to be a filed bug though…

Comment: I'll swear that there's a document out there which says *why* this is the case, but after that I can't really say much.